# Matplotlib colormap background

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, imshow

I'm working on a function which will generate an image based on a colormap. This is what I tried:

```py
#the variable 'name' is supplied before
gradient = np.vstack((np.linspace(0, 1, 256), np.linspace(0, 1, 256)))
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap(name))
plt.savefig("color.png", transparent=True)
```

However, there is a transparent border when I export it:
[image: Final output]

You will be able to see the border when you open it in a new tab. Is there a way to remove this border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `plt.axis('off')` to turn off the axis frame and `plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, right = 1, bottom = 0, left = 0)` to remove the pad around the image.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = 'jet'
gradient = np.vstack((np.linspace(0, 1, 256), np.linspace(0, 1, 256)))
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect = 'auto', cmap = plt.get_cmap(name))
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, right = 1, bottom = 0, left = 0)
plt.savefig("color.png", transparent = True)
```

[image]